# Top Questions of the Week #7

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 7 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://superuser.blogoverflow.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each we week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a question I think deserves some attention:

[**What's the best way to spray paint the inside of my case?**](https://superuser.com/questions/133864/whats-the-best-way-to-spray-paint-the-inside-of-my-case)

After hearing an interesting anecdote about anti-static orthotics causing workers to get statically charged in highly inflammatory work environments... I view this question in a somewhat... different light and think that such questions deserve to have some time in the spotlight!

[image: This is what I imagine the factory looked like afterwards...]

Comment: I've always to showcase my spray painted pc case ;)

Comment: Is this from orbit though?